# Embedding c# windows application (.exe) in a webpart

Tags: windows, embed, web-parts, exe

Is there is a way to embed an application executable inside a webpart? is there any kind of a webpart available in sharepoint.

If not, then is it possible to create my own webpart and some how place my windows application there so that when a user login to a sharepoint site he can view the main winodws applciation screen on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the code for the exe?  If so you may be able to port it to a UserControl and put that in your WebPart.  Development experience required.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to display an windows application inside a web form.

You can do that by creating an ActiveX component with your winform application and calling it from your custom webpart code. You can also to extract your commom business logic and reuse it between your win/web apps.

Comment: Thanks guys.. i better get started!!